# Overview page with links to other microservices

Tags: spring, spring-restdocs

I have faced with a problem of creating overview page in gateway service with links to documentations of all other microservices using Spring Rest Docs. I have microservice architecture, so gateway service and other service are different projects.

Gateway service just have only RouteLocator and CORS configurations. From Spring Rest Docs I have understand that I can attach only to spring application context only if I'm using `@component` or `@service`.

How to make an overview page with links on all documented microservices in gateway service?

Comment: Is writing a static page an option?

Comment: I did it as static now but still interested in more dynamic way to update common documentation page

Comment: Can you access the downstream services through an URL? If so, you could use WebTestClient (use bindToServer with the URL of the service you want to test) or even RestAssured to write tests with documentation and include it in the gateway's build.